# My service gone Crazy

Tags: android

My service is sending non stop sms messages without stop.... He doesnt care about the Stopself() command... its just continue to run even if i destroy it...
This is just annoying ...

Thats my service code:

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service {
    // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;
        //protected LocationManager lm;     
         protected Location location;// location
         public LocationManager lm ;

        double lat; // latitude
        double Long; // longitude
        double line;
        double ship  ;
        double b   ;
        double[] d = new double[4];
        String numberr;
        WakeLock wakeLock;
        final LocationListener mlocList = new MyLocationList();


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            // no network provider is enabled
            } else {

            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0,  mlocList);


                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (lm != null) {
                    location = lm
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }
                }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            else  {
                if (location == null) {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                0,
                                0,  mlocList);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "WOW", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (lm != null) {
                        location = lm
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                       }
                    }
                 }
              }     
           }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


        if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle


            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
             numberr = intent.getStringExtra("number");


            int p=0,j,i=1,t,success=0;


            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(message);

            while(m.find())
            {
               double  k = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
               d[p]=k;
               p++;
               }
          System.out.println(d[0]+","+d[1]+":"+d[2]+","+d[3]+"THE REAL DEAL");

        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Log", "Bundle is null");
        }

        if(location!= null )
        {
         lat =location.getLatitude(); // Updated lat
         Long = location.getLongitude(); // Updated long

         canGetLocation= inRange(d[1],d[0],d[3],d[2],Long,lat); 
       System.out.println(canGetLocation);

         if (canGetLocation){


         SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(numberr, null, "I'm", null, null);     
          if (lm!=null){

          lm.removeUpdates(mlocList);
         lm=null;
          }

          stopSelf(); 

         }
              }
        return START_STICKY;

    }

     public class MyLocationList implements LocationListener
     {


    public void onLocationChanged( Location pocation) {

         if (pocation != null){
         lat=pocation.getLatitude();
         Long=pocation.getLongitude();


         canGetLocation= inRange(d[1],d[0],d[3],d[2],Long,lat); 
         if (canGetLocation){

         SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(numberr, null, "I'm In the line area!", null, null);

          if (lm!=null){

          lm.removeUpdates(mlocList);
         lm=null;
          }

          stopSelf(); 
            }
         }
     }

     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS Disable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         isGPSEnabled=false;
     }

     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         isGPSEnabled=true;
     }

     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
         if (lm!=null){
              lm.removeUpdates(mlocList);
              lm=null;

              } 



    }
    public static boolean inRange(double start_x, double start_y, double end_x, double end_y,
            double point_x, double point_y) {
double dx = end_x - start_x;
double dy = end_y - start_y;
double innerProduct = (point_x - start_x)*dx + (point_y - start_y)*dy;
return 0 <= innerProduct && innerProduct <= dx*dx + dy*dy;
}


}
```

Please help...

Comment: Indent your code pls.

Comment: what do you mean by " Indent"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: You can use Ctrl + Shift + F in Eclipse to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `START_STICKY` with `START_NOT_STICKY`

[Documentation for START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

Comment: Did it now.. doesnt help

Comment: its not about start_sticky i think its a problem with the code but i cant see what's wrong... it just sending this sms message like in a while(true) loop... Why ?

Comment: you put your Sending sms to your onLocationChanged listener , so i think changing every location will raise an event to sending sms.maybe changing the listener part helps.

Comment: changed the if statement in both places..still getting non stop sms messages... :(

Comment: try starting and stopping the service from an activity using startservice and stopservice

Comment: I cant... this service runs from smslistener broadcast receiver the service run's without activity....